# Can OpenAI chat completions be fully deterministic?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a use case where fully deterministic responses from OpenAI's API would be highly desirable. Playing around with temperature however does not seem to be able to generate full determinism.

```
import openai


openai.organization = "org-..."
openai.api_key = "sk-..."

result = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
    messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are Daffy Duck."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "How should I make difficult decisions around balancing work and family life?"},
    ],
    temperature = 0.0
)

print(result["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
```

Each time a different response is generated.

Is there a way to make it fully deterministic, other than just loading it up with constraints?

Comment: Can floats that the tensors are made of be fully deterministic? :)
For "full determinism" there would have to be a KV cache on their side. It might be possible to implement it yourself (depending on your scenario) to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `temperature` parameter with the `top_p` parameter:

```py
result = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are Daffy Duck."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "How should I make difficult decisions around balancing work and family life?"},
    ],
    top_p=0
)
```

This reliably results in "Well, well, well, if it isn't a quacking good question! Balancing..." for me.

Comment: You might have found a specific prompt that's consistent as much as you text it, but setting the top_p=0 doesn't always result in determinism for OpenAI chat models

Comment: Oh, too bad. :-( Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

As of November, 2023, OpenAi Openai has introduced a seed parameter into their [api](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) that can produce semi-deterministic responses by setting the seed parameter in the api. The seed should be set to an integer.

The responses are only semi-deterministic because sometimes the results can be different with the same seed.  However, it looks like in most cases the result will be the same.

Although Openai do not state this, it looks to me that the seed is used to as the seed for their random number generator, so that the random numbers produced in generating the output are the same each time if the seed is provided.

Comment: I'm curious what "almost deterministic" looks like for other people. I'm using version 1.3.5 of the python library with gpt-3.5-turbo. I have temperature set to 0 and seed set to 42. 

With those settings, I'm getting exactly the same answer with the same inputs about 50% of the time, almost exactly the same answer 70% of the time, and something meaningfully different about 5% of the time.

Is that similar to what others are seeing, or are other people seeing more consistent responses?

Comment: The linked page does not exist anymore. However, the seed parameter is explained in the [OpenAI API reference](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create)